# xAxis,yAxis and zAxis are not encapsulated. Are they special keywords?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Now I want to encapsulate a json-formatted parameter as an object with @requestbody receipt, But I find that xAxis, yAxis and zAxis cannot be encapsulated. Are these three special keywords? If I change to xaxis,yaxis and zaxis, it will be successful.
The picture is the one I changed to x,y and tested.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxF5E.png)

Comment: They are not special keywords. Would you mind showing the classes of the object you need to receive and the endpoint? It'll be easier to detect the error.

Comment: Received the object property picture uploaded, thank you